# Links between 3 tables shows 1 records instead of 254 records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to know some things about linking in MySQL.
There are my exposed problems:

I work in an IT Support Service, and I'm making an IP management web hosted panel.

Here are my tables:
[image: tables]

Here is my code

```
SELECT *
FROM IP
    INNER JOIN VLAN ON IP.GATEWAY = VLAN.GATEWAY
    INNER JOIN SCHOOLBUILDING ON VLAN.SCHOOLBUILDING = SCHOOLBUILDING.NAME
    INNER JOIN SCHOOL ON SCHOOLBUILDING.SCHOOLNAME = SCHOOL.NAME
WHERE SCHOOL.NAME = 'mySchoolName'
```

When I run this I got only 1 record which is the last of the table IP.

I deeply expose my problem :

the dashboard page, you choose the part of the city
[image: dashboard]

School Building selection page

[image: school]

VLAN Selection
[image: VLAN Selection]

Comment: Firstly you need to test your query with small data, If you directly implement it then you will never find where your logic is wrong. And  this happen most of the time when you join more than 2 tables.

Comment: I tested, to display only the ip's and it works perfectly, as long as i try to make an `INNER JOIN` it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you include some sample data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your joins between VLAN and IP were incorrect the field names are `IP_GATEWAY` not just `GATEWAY`

```
SELECT *
FROM IP i
INNER JOIN VLAN v ON I.IP_GATEWAY = V.IP_GATEWAY
INNER JOIN SCHOOLBUILDING SB ON V.SCHOOLBUILDING = SB.NAME
INNER JOIN SCHOOL S ON SB.SCHOOLNAME = S.NAME
WHERE S.NAME = 'mySchoolName'
```

Also if this *still* doesn't work then i would use `FULL OUTER JOINS` for them all and work backwards.

```
SELECT *
FROM IP i
FULL OUTER JOIN VLAN v ON I.IP_GATEWAY = V.IP_GATEWAY
FULL OUTER JOIN SCHOOLBUILDING SB ON V.SCHOOLBUILDING = SB.NAME
FULL OUTER JOIN SCHOOL S ON SB.SCHOOLNAME = S.NAME
WHERE S.NAME = 'mySchoolName'
```

Comment: I didn't wanted to write it again, sorry for this.

Comment: No, all three, because the WHERE removes any NULLs created by the outer joins

Comment: in this query, wheather you use left join, right join or full outer join or inner join for last join  (LEFT JOIN IP
  ON IP.GATEWAY = VLAN.GATEWAY), No difference, becuase when you use where clause, it will automatically convert into inner join. you can try with changing last join

Answer (score 0):

You probably want OUTER instead of INNER joins:
All details for this specific school even if there's no VLAN/IP.

```
SELECT *
FROM IP
    RIGHT JOIN VLAN ON IP.GATEWAY = VLAN.GATEWAY
    RIGHT JOIN SCHOOLBUILDING ON VLAN.SCHOOLBUILDING = SCHOOLBUILDING.NAME
    RIGHT JOIN SCHOOL ON SCHOOLBUILDING.SCHOOLNAME = SCHOOL.NAME
WHERE SCHOOL.NAME = 'mySchoolName'
```

As most people prefer LEFT joins (easier to follow, you start with the most important table):

```
SELECT *
FROM SCHOOL
LEFT JOIN SCHOOLBUILDING 
  ON SCHOOLBUILDING.SCHOOLNAME = SCHOOL.NAME
LEFT JOIN VLAN
  ON VLAN.SCHOOLBUILDING = SCHOOLBUILDING.NAME
LEFT JOIN IP
  ON IP.GATEWAY = VLAN.GATEWAY
WHERE SCHOOL.NAME = 'mySchoolName'
```